# "Difficulty" opcode pushes always 0x0 to stack

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, genesis, bytecode

Currently, I do some experiments with Geth-EVM and opcode execution. During the experiments, I observed that the `DIFFICULTY` opcode always pushs `0x0` to the EVM stack regardless of how I set the difficulty value in the genesis config.file. How can I interpret this and how can I define the difficulty value?

I execute the EVM with the following command:

```
/home/user/ethereum/evms/geth-evm-1.8.0-stable 
--code 5a5b5b325932443a4332364333348942594458453441344130349944585b600960d360513900 
--prestate /home/user/ethereum/geth_genesis.json 
--gas 1048575 --sender 0x054fcf7870c50924ecbddd38c26e159d2cc78232 
--receiver 0xa31741b8972eea1991a9093284ad16bab63b9c18 --nomemory --json run
```

This is my genesis config file:

```
{"alloc": {
"0x123456789a123456789a123456789a123456789a": {
  "balance": "0x2bcb2dca0cded",
  "code": "0x1337",
  "nonce": "0x0"
},
"0x123456789a123456789a123456789a123456789c": {
  "balance": "0x9a815cb917edb",
  "code": "0x1337",
  "nonce": "0x0"
},
"0x123456789a123456789a123456789a123456789e": {
  "balance": "0x1c63ab403d7514",
  "code": "0x1337",
  "nonce": "0x0"
},
"0x123456789a321232189a123456789a123456789f": {
  "balance": "0xd3f6cdb0ae123",
  "code": "0x1337",
  "nonce": "0x0"
},
"0x333456789a123456789a123453289a1234512893": {
  "balance": "0x26b012410311d",
  "code": "0x1337",
  "nonce": "0x0"
}
},
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "config": {
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "daoForkBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "homesteadBlock": 0
},
    "difficulty": "0x01",
    "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "gasLimit": "0x3D0900",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
    "number": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use difficulty lower than 2048 because the function that calculates the difficulty divides it by 2048 and if you use 1, you will end up with 0 since it is an integer division ( 1 / 2048 = 0). This parameter is configurable in

```
config/protocol_params.go

DifficultyBoundDivisor
```

Try to set it to 1, maybe it will work. But if you don't want to have these problems, just set your difficulty to 2100 or above

Comment: I understand that, but regardless of the value it always pushes 0x0 to the stack. During the last execution I set the value to "0x9999999" and i got 0x0.

Comment: try to "push"  `GasLimit`, if it is not 0, then it is the divisor.

Comment: I will try that. However, I tested the same bytecode sequence with with the Parity implementation of EVM. This implementation takes exactly the difficult value from the genesis file. Is there a reason why Geth uses the divisor?

Comment: the divisor is part of the difficulty function, everybody has it implemented the same way otherwise  you will not reach consensus. To run bytecode you have to have a preinitialized environment , in other words , a `types.Header`, a `state.StateDb`  and `vm.Context` objects. In your case `Difficulty` is 0 , this means `types.Header` is not initialized,  Alter the function `vm.NewEVM()` and dump all the parameters passed to this function to console, this way you will  have a better understanding of what part of the enviroment is not configured properly.

Comment: I will try this. But actually I use the standalone EVM executable. So types.Header should be initialized?!

Comment: `types.Header` is the block header, which stores Difficulty, and the EVM gets it from there.  In your case if Difficulty is 0 then this object is not instantiated or is wrongly set up

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17216 it is a bug that the EVM does not initialize these values. But of course, you are right, too. Thanks for your help!!